# Device.device.model returns iPhone6 for iPhone5s device

Tags: ios, ionic2

I'm working on an ionic2 app and I'm checking the device model using
Device in ionic native.

I'm testing on iPhone5s device but the value returned by Device.device.model is
iPhone6

Device.device.model is working correctly for android devices

Answer (score 1):

The identifier for iphone5s is iPhone6,1 or iPhone6,2
Device.device.model returns the identifier 
Please read https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models